# MySQL select rows by max(column) by another column in SQL while using GROUP BY WEEK?

Tags: mysql

For each week I want to select the rows which have the highest weight for each distinct value of reps

```
-------------------------------------
| id | reps | weight |     date     |
| 1  |  1   |  15    |   2015-06-10 |
| 2  |  2   |  29    |   2015-06-12 |
| 3  |  1   |  30    |   2015-06-13 |
| 4  |  4   |  11    |   2015-06-14 |
| 5  |  1   |  15    |   2015-06-29 |
| 6  |  1   |  9     |   2015-06-30 |
```

and I would like it to return

```
-------------------------------------
| id | reps | weight |     date     |
| 2  |  2   |  29    |   2015-06-12 |
| 3  |  1   |  30    |   2015-06-13 |
| 4  |  4   |  11    |   2015-06-14 |
| 5  |  1   |  15    |   2015-06-29 |
```

I've tried

```
SELECT MAX(weight) as weight, reps, date, id FROM log_items
GROUP BY reps, WEEK(date)
```

But it seems to return completely random results, I have also tried using sub queries but they didn't work either (I'm guessing I was doing it wrong)

Comment: Dates adhere to a specific format/ data type in SQL. Fix that, then get back to us.

Comment: Sorry I just made up some random sample data to help explain the scenario, changed it to sql standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM log_items
WHERE (reps, WEEK(date), weight ) in (
      SELECT reps, WEEK(date) , MAX(weight)
      FROM log_items
      GROUP BY reps, WEEK(date)
 )
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bf84/9